# I have this three objects next to each other, but as soon as i resize the screen it doesn´t appear responsive

Tags: html, css

How could i make this three objects responsive so when i smaller the screen for an phone example how could i make it just move down not stay to the side of the website. Could someone just give me an hint or a soulution of this. I have other objects on the website with similar code and they actually move down when resizing the website. The text also moves to the side, what have i done wrong?

```css
.text-1 {
  width: 900px;
  margin-right: 130px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #888;
  text-align: left;
}
.text-1 p{
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: left;
}
#box {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
.first {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  max-height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 2px;
  float: left;
  margin: 30px;
}

.second {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  max-height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 2px;
  float: left;
  margin: 30px;
}

.third {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  max-height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 2px;
  float: left;
  margin: 30px;
}
.third p{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 32px;
 color: #888;
 font-weight: 300;
 }
.first p{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 32px;
 color: #888;
 font-weight: 300;
}
.second p{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 32px;
 color: #888;
 font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <h2>Vår process<hr width="150px"></h2>
  <div class="text-1"><p> VI HJÄLPER DIG MED ALLT </p></div>
  <div class="first wow fadeInLeft"><img src="assets/image/kontakt.png"><h3>KONTAKT</H3><p>Kontakta oss genom telefon eller vårat kontaktformulär på hemsidan.</p></div>
  <div class="second wow fadeInUp"><img src="assets/image/arende.png"><H3>GRANSKAN</H3><P>Vi går igenom ditt ärende och ser om vi har möjlighet och utföra jobbet.</P></div>
  <div class="third wow fadeInRight"><img src="assets/image/leverans.png"><H3>LEVERANS</H3><P>Vi kommer hem till dig och fixar det du behöver hjälp med.</P></div>
</div>
```

[image: First it looks like this]
[image: after when i resize it looks like this]

Comment: How you want it to look like on smaller screens?

Comment: You have fixed units, it wouldn't be responsive.

Comment: Yes. Since `text-1` is 900 pixels wide, the rest of the site is not going to be narrower than that. Remove the `width` (or, change it to `max-width`) and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have used fixed width, instead of that give it in percentage. And moreover add meta tag in your html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed width in .text-1. If you remove that they will collapse!